# PHP Multiple Curl Requests

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I'm currently using Curl for PHP a lot. It takes a lot of time to get results of about 100 pages each time. For every request i'm using code like this

```
$ch = curl_init();

// get source

curl_close($ch);
```

What are my options to speed things up?

How should I use the `multi_init()` etc?

Comment: Answer of this thread is over here [Multiple API requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538046/multiple-api-calls-in-a-class/47068115#47068115)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- Reuse the same cURL handler ($ch) without running curl_close. This will speed it up just a little bit.
- Use [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/curl_multi_init) to run the processes in parallel. This can have a tremendous effect.

Comment: I now use a curl_multi_init for about 10 requests at a time. Takes about 5 for 10 requests =D

Answer (score 8):

take curl_multi - it is far better. Save the handshakes - they are not needed every time!

Answer (score 1):

when i use code given in "http://php.net/curl_multi_init", response of 2 requests are conflicting.
But the code written in below link, returns each response separately (in array format)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21362749/3177302

Answer (score 0):

or take `pcntl_fork`, `fork` some new threads to execute `curl_exec`. But it's not as good as `curl_multi`.